# PhpStorm with Docker vendor directory

Tags: docker, phpstorm

I'm trying to dockerize my Laravel application and all works fine. All my containers works 100%.

The only problem is the `vendor` directory created via Composer.

This is a part of my `Dockerfile`

```
COPY . .
RUN composer update --no-scripts
```

Since this command is executed inside the container, the `vendor` directory is not the host, so PhpStorm do not detect it and all the includes are marked as not found

I should install `vendor` on the host too ?

Comment: You might try to just share the volume with a host. Add the local path on a host (a mounting point for docker volume sharing) into the project's Include Paths on PHP Interpreter settings page. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host